# How would i make this php link _blank?

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink

Here's my code:

```
$facebook = isset( $ct_options['ct_fb_url'] ) ? esc_attr( $ct_options['ct_fb_url'] ) : '';
```

how would i make this open in a new tab, or _blank.

this string is actually displaying the link in wordpress. the ct_fb_url is pulling the http://facebook.com/link from the theme settings and plugging it into an icon that is echoed on the page.

EDIT: Thanks Brad. I should have scrolled down a bit more, and I found this:

```
 <li class="facebook"><a href="<?php echo $facebook; ?>"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
```

I think i know what to do from here :) Sorry about being so ambiguous. I thought it was a PHP syntax i wasn't familiar with in the beginning.

Comment: Where is the URL in this? You can't expect us to help you if you're not providing more information. What does `ct_options['ct_fb_url']` return? Does it return a link? What are you echoing out onto the page?

Comment: `echo "<a href=\"$facebook\" target=\"_blank\">Link</a>";`?

Comment: apologies - i thought this was standard syntax. its in Wordpress (as shown in the tag, but i failed to explain that.) 
The URL is linking to settings added into a wordpress theme options. when i put the link in the settings, it pulls the link from there.

This is actually displaying the link.

Comment: How is the icon echoed? Paste that script, look for `$facebook` in your code and tell us what you find. What you've pasted simply declares the url, we need to see how the URL is actually echoed

Comment: I guess I wasn't far off.

Comment: echo "<a href=\"$facebook\" target=\"_blank\">Link</a>";

Comment: @Fred-ii- no you were right on. both of you were. sorry about the confusion!

Comment: you're welcome, call it a group effort, cheers

Answer (score 3):

```
echo "<a href=\"$facebook\" target=\"_blank\">Link</a>";
```

Was right... thanks @Brad and @Fred -ii- you were both helpful

Answer (score 1):

Seems simpler to do this:

```
<li class="facebook"><a href="<?php echo $facebook; ?>" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
```

Comment: basically the same, but yeah... thats more or less what I did.

Comment: Basically the same, but I'm a huge fan of clean code.   It's easier to read this way.  Also, don't make PHP do more work than it needs to.   Not that it's a significant overhead, but it's less efficient to process things with echos.   Once you get into bigger apps, like Magento and stuff, it actually makes a difference.